# Template Literals How To Make a ?Universal Rule?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm new to coding but I am using template literals in a project using css variables.  this example sets all the variables in one shot inside a function. this is referring to inputs which all have an eventlistener on them.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
```

I want to set another rule for a span to display the values.  right now I am doing each one individually like this.

```
heightDisplay.innerHTML = height.value + 'px';
widthDisplay.innerHTML = width.value + 'px';
```

all the span's ids will be " this.name + 'Display' "
I want to right a rule that sets them all at once using the literals(similar to the rule that sets the variables) instead of writing 30 lines of code.

I can't figure out the syntax to add Display on there and i don't know where to put the back ticks.

I assume this is possible, since pretty much everything in Javascript is.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you provide the whole html - code ?

Comment: Please show us the complete code. What is `this`, what are `suffix`, `height` and `width`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have an iteration where this Code-Line is Executed:`document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);`

In this Iteration you can set the Values of your spans like this:

```
var Span = document.querySelector(`[id*= ${this.name}]`);

Span.innerHTML =  this.value+ "px";
```

Edit:
The querySelector - function gets a css-selector as a parameter. the [] - Brackets is a css selector that gets an element with an atribute (in this case id) and a value (this.name). The *= between them means, that you can select an element that has a substring in the value of the atribute.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I don't quite get it.  We capitalize Span why? And I haven't use [] inside a literal before or an *.

Comment: I'm going to have a problem.  I have some spans I want to make that will have 'deg' as a label or no label at all. could I enter in the labels like 'px' manually and instead of `Span.innerHTML` use `Span.prepend`??

Comment: so you want to have in special cases a "deg" instead of a "px" ? Then you need to add a if-statement before this code-line:`Span.innerHTML =  this.value+ "px";` then you have to decide whether you want a "px" or a deg. Example: `if(degInsteadOfPX){Span.innerHTML =  this.value+ "deg";
}else{Span.innerHTML =  this.value+ "px";}` Note that you need to set `degInsteadOfPX` somehow and decide whether you want a deg or a px in your span. Btw can you mark my answer as correct (i answered your question correctly :) )

Comment: thanks.  i ended up using the + suffix instead of 'px'.  I forgot i had already sort of solved this problem.  what i am curious about is the captialization of Span (why) and the * after id(are the [] a type of conditional that matches the span id with this.name with the * meaning anything can come after such as Display in this case)??

Comment: I edited the answer. For more Information look on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

Comment: Are all your questions answered or can i help with other problems?

Comment: I am good to go.  You helped me out big time for that feature I wanted to add.

Comment: glad to hear. You could mark my answer as "best answer" if you want to